# How to use json_decode?

Tags: php, json

I have the following Json file:

```
[{"Datum":"21-07-2017","Zeit":"21:48","Menge":"545465476"},{"Datum":"21-07-2017","Zeit":"21:51","Menge":"78"},{"Datum":"21-07-2017","Zeit":"21:53","Menge":"456"}]
```

The Json validator says its ok.

But still I cannot this Json file via php_decode(). Instead I am getting "bool(false)"

My code

```
$jso  = json_encode($jfile);
var_dump(json_decode($jso));
$error = json_last_error();
```

What am I doing wrong?

This script is saving an input to a txt database in Json format.

Comment: How do you declare `$jfile`?

Comment: Show us `print_r($jfile);` before the encode

Comment: Why encode first if its already JSON???

Comment: https://3v4l.org/M5N9f

Comment: print_r($jfile) shows "Resource id #8"

Comment: Resource id #8 is a database error, not php nor JSON. So, post your real/full code.

Comment: I just added the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON encode and decode look correct. You can refer to the following resources for confirmation:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

So the problem, most likely, lies in the way you get the json into the functions. In your case this is done with a variable "$jfile".

I suggest you do a var_dump of the $jfile variable to see what data it holds, if any.

My first guess, as others have pointed out as well, is that you're reading the json from a file (hence $jfile). This is usually done with the "file_get_contents" function which is described in detail [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

---

## A working example

Your directory structure should look like this:

```
.
├── readjson.php
├── some_json_data.json
```

And your php code should look something like this:

```
<?php 

$jfile = file_get_contents('some_json_data.json');
var_dump($jfile)

$jso  = json_encode($jfile);
var_dump($jso);

$decoded_json = json_decode($jso);
var_dump($decoded_json);

$error = json_last_error();
?>
```

Note how I add more var_dump's and variables to explicitly monitor the state of the json objects. This might be helpful when learning new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to first get the file into php, so $jso will hold json data (in terms of file contents)

```
    $jso  = file_get_contents('JSON_FILE_PATH');
    //then simply use json_decode
    var_dump(json_decode($jso));
```

Comment: Hi there, OP is using "$jfile" to load in the json, best to keep it that way for now so it's easier to follow for the OP.